# What does CloudBlobContainer.SetPermissionsAsync return?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Got a problem with this code returning a "cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable container" error. Tried to type a correct Task<> but can't find out what it does return..

```
try
        {
            blobContainer.BeginCreateIfNotExists(async b =>
                {
                    EDIT: await blobContainer.SetPermissionsAsync(new BlobContainerPermissions { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob });
                    var r = (b.AsyncState as CloudBlobContainer).EndCreateIfNotExists(b);
                }, blobContainer);
            return blobContainer;
        }
```

Comment: Use `F12` (Go To Definition) and look at the method signature displayed to you in the IDE.

Comment: "A Task object that represents the current operation." That is about the only information I can find, which I don't know what to do with...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is mixing [APM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [TAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx) methods. It's a lot easier to just use TAP:

```
await blobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
await blobContainer.SetPermissionsAsync(new BlobContainerPermissions { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob });
```

`Task` is a type that represents an asynchronous operation *without* a return value. So, when you `await` it there's no return value.

You may find my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful.

Comment: Thank you, I am just getting a understanding of how to use APM and TAP and seem to getting them mixed up, so I will read your blogpost and make notes and hopefully it will stick! I edited my code with removing the var permissions bit and i executes just fine.